# Multiple text layouts in one LyX document

Tags: lyx, indentation, lyx-layouts

In general I want to use a 3mm spacing as my text layout for space between paragraphs.

However, this produces an extremely spaced out Table of Contents. Hence, I would like to use an indent paragraph text layout just for the few pages that are my list of figures and table of contents.

I have tried selecting the region of text that I want it to be paragraph and go to Document --> Settings --> Text Layout to change the text layout, but this changes the text layout for the entire document.

Is there a way to change between two forms of text layouts within a single LyX document easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the default (indented) style in the document settings. In your document, add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or Insert --> TeX code) right after your content lists, and write

```
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{3mm}
```

in this.

When you change the document settings to having 3mm of vertical space separating your paragraphs, LyX inserts the above in the preamble. By issuing them after the TOC, LoT, etc., the setting will only apply to whatever comes after that ERT.